# Using SAS macrovariables inside a SAS data step

Tags: arrays, sas, sas-macro

I have a macrovariable  ***&var_list*** which stores a list of integer variable names from the dataset ***have***.

```
%put &var_list.;

id trt grade
```

Now I want to create a new dataset ***want*** where each of the above variable names itself becomes an array- and I need this done using macrovariables, because eventually my ***&varlist*** will have about a 1000 variables. I want macro code that creates a new data set where all the existing variables become arrays of length 4. Like so:

```
data want;

array id_var{4};

array trt_var{4};

array grade_var{4};

set have;

run;
```

I have tried the following macro code but it doesn't run correctly. I am trying to iterate through ***&var_list***, concatenate the string "var" to the variable name and also add a {4} at the end to declare each variable as an array. But SAS complains that the keyword  "array" is an undeclared array variable. It doesn't realise that I am trying to use the keyword array inside the %do macro. Also, what do I do about the {4} in the declaration statement?

```
%put &var_list.;
```

id trt grade

```
%macro getArrayData(dat);

data &dat;

%do i=1 %to 3;

       array %scan(&var_list,&i.)_var {4};

%end;

set have;
run;
%mend getArrayData;

%getArrayData(want);
```

Comment: Do you actually need to define arrays?  The code you posted does not use the arrays for anything. What is it that you are actually trying to do?

Comment: @Tom it is not my own code - I was given this, and asked to automate it using macros. I also felt it doesn't strictly need arrays, but that's not within my remit to decide :-)

Comment: So eliminate the ARRAY and just generate one LENGTH statement using variable lists instead.  Instead of `array id_var{4}; array trt_var{4}` just generate `length id_var1-id_var4 trt_var1-trt_var4 8;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside: *With the idea of eventually having 1,000 `{4}` item arrays you might want to consider using one 2-dimensional array `{1000,4}`*

What does the log show when you turn on `OPTIONS MPRINT;`

The code you show does work correctly.  I recommend coding `var_list` as a macro parameter instead of relying on a global macro variable.

```
data have;
run;

%macro getArrayData(dat, var_list);

data &dat;

%do i=1 %to 3;

       array %scan(&var_list,&i.)_var {4};

%end;

  set have;
run;
%mend getArrayData;

options mprint;

%getArrayData(want, a b c);
```

Log

```
56   %getArrayData(want, a b c);
MPRINT(GETARRAYDATA):   data want;
MPRINT(GETARRAYDATA):   array a_var {4};
MPRINT(GETARRAYDATA):   array b_var {4};
MPRINT(GETARRAYDATA):   array c_var {4};
MPRINT(GETARRAYDATA):   set have;
MPRINT(GETARRAYDATA):   run;
```

Depending on what columns are in `have` the above will create variables
`a_var1-a_var4 , b_var1-bvar4 , cvar1-cvar4`

In general, a space separated list in macro is iterated as

```
%do index = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&list,%str( )));
  %let item = %sysfunc(scan(countw(&list,%str( )));

  /* do things with &item */

%end;
```